# Writing/Reading To/From File Windows 8.1 AppStore App

Tags: c#, async-await, windows

I have a Windows 8.1 App from which I want to write to and read from an XML file that is put in the "Assets" folder in the Application package.

I call the following method from the page constructor after the `this.InitializeComponent();` line:

```
private async void ReadXML()
    {
        var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appdata:///Assets/gameInfo.xml");
        StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);

        XmlDocument reader = new XmlDocument();
        reader.LoadXml(file.ToString());
        XmlNodeList nodes = reader.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;

        string attr = nodes[0].Attributes[0].InnerText;
        int bestTime;
        if (attr != null && int.TryParse(attr, out bestTime))
            BestTime = bestTime;
    }
```

When I navigate to the page that contains this code and it runs I get an ArgumentException thrown on the `StorageFile file...` line. Here is the exception detail:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at LightsOutApp.Random4x4.<ReadXML>d__0.MoveNext()
  InnerException:
```

Does anyone have any idea why this exception is being thrown? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please provide the full exception details. Click the [Copy Exception Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx) button then pate the information as a edit to your question.

Comment: I did that. Thank you for showing me that trick!!

Comment: Where are you catching this exception?

Comment: No this is being thrown and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing ms-app in stead of ms-appdata and it fixed that error. Thank you for your help.